# Disable Docker in Visual Studio

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017

I have a Visual Studio Solution that I've been working with. This solution has a console app in it. Notably, I've been running Windows within a Bootcamp partition on my MacBook Pro.

A developer on my team wanted to use Docker. I agreed, thinking it wouldn't impact the console app itself. However, I can no longer compile the console app since Docker has been added. When I attempt to compile the solution, I see:

```
Visual Studio Container Tools requires Docker CE for Windows.  To get it, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=847268

For more info, please see: http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting
```

Here's the problem, since I'm running Windows via a Bootcamp Partition, I can't run Docker (from my understanding). Is there a way to disable Docker just for my myself? If so, how? I don't want to undo what the other dev has done. However, I can't setup a brand new environment at this time.

Answer (score 0):

My need is similar:  disable Docker completely, but without uninstalling it.

So, this may help.  But

- My use case is different: I want to as nimbly as possible switch between VMWare and Docker.
- My environment is different:  I have a non-macbook PC and I'm only running Windows.

So YMMV.

This worked for my use case:

- In the services control panel, disable the Docker for Windows Service or set it to manual start.
- On the task manager startup tab, disable Docker for Windows.
- For my use case only, there additional changes for VMWare.  Disable DeviceGuard and CredentialsGuard per article at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/credential-guard-manage.

Hope this helps for you.